# Using query in google sheet to fetch desired result based on some filters

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I need to generate a report using query.

Data looks like as follows:

```
Model   SerialNumber    IdentityNumber    Status       EmployeeID
Lenovo  12abc           L-001             Issued        E-50
Apple   13abc           M-001             Issued        E-50
Lenovo  12abc           L-001             InStock       E-50
Lenovo  12abc           L-001             Issued        E-51
Lenovo  12abc           L-001             InStock       E-51
Lenovo  12abc           L-001             Issued        E-50
```

filter criteria's are employeeid, stockstatus and identitynumber. As mentioned in above data identity number L-001 issued to empolyeeid E-50 and after sometime employee(E-50) returned this asset so current assets with employee is M-001 2nd row only. I need to get this data using query in google sheet.

I got the result after crating an additional column where I updated that column with 0 and 1. if asset is in stock than 1 else 0. But in this solution I have to update the additional column for 1st row as well with flag 1 at time when employee return the asset. like below:

```
Model   SerialNumber    IdentityNumber    Status       EmployeeID    Flag
Lenovo  12abc           L-001             Issued        E-50         1
Apple   13abc           M-001             Issued        E-50         0
Lenovo  12abc           L-001             InStock       E-50         1
```

Is there any solution to get desired result without using additional column?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: its sample data and structure is same.

Comment: what formulas did you use for flag?

Comment: =QUERY(A1:F,"select A,B,C,D,E where E='E-50' and F=0")

Comment: problem with this is that I had to update flag as 1  when I issued that asset not only when asset was return by employee. I hope you got my point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A:E, {""; IF(A2:A="",,IF(ISEVEN(IFNA(
 VLOOKUP(A2:A&B2:B&C2:C, SORT({A2:A&B2:B&C2:C, IF(A2:A="",,
 COUNTIFS(A2:A&B2:B&C2:C, A2:A&B2:B&C2:C, 
 ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A)))}, 2, 0), 2, 0))), 1, 0))}}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5 
  where Col5 = 'E-50' 
    and Col6 = 0", 1))
```

[image]

---

### fix:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({A1:E1; QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORTN(SORT({A2:F, 
 IF(ISEVEN(VLOOKUP(A2:A&B2:B&C2:C&E2:E, SORTN(SORT({A2:A&B2:B&C2:C&E2:E, IF(A2:A="",, 
 COUNTIFS(A2:A&B2:B&C2:C&E2:E, A2:A&B2:B&C2:C&E2:E,  ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A)))}, 2, 0), 
 99^99, 2, 1, 0), 2, 0)), 1, 0), VLOOKUP(A2:A&B2:B&C2:C&E2:E, 
 SORTN(SORT({A2:A&B2:B&C2:C&E2:E, IF(A2:A="",, 
 COUNTIFS(A2:A&B2:B&C2:C&E2:E, A2:A&B2:B&C2:C&E2:E,  ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A)))}, 2, 0), 
 99^99, 2, 1, 0), {2, 1}, 0), ROW(A2:A)}, 10, 0, 8, 0), 99^99, 2, 9, 0), 99^99, 7), 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5 where Col5 = 'E-50' and Col7 = 0", 0)})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I added more sample data, formula is working fine on data provided earlier. Now scenario has changed asset L-001 issued to another person E-51 and E-51 returned asset L-001 after work in rows 4 and 5. Now L-001 issued to  previous person E-50 in this case what formula need to be use. Expected result is row 2 and 6 only

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KYtJzWc0fzNc0UfokaSKJespx57t7AOXuPv3E4vB1V0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: please check the sheet link given above

Comment: Hi, this helped me a lot, I  added 1 more sheet in that google file I need to update stock sheet, column name "stockstatus" status should be instock/issued automatically using a formula which checks the transaction sheet with a common field serialnumber, in both sheets to update the status properly. formula should update the status if asset based on your previous solution is issued in transaction sheet